# Shrimp like creature in spring mountain water

Tags: drinking-water

May I know if someone know about this tiny plankton shrimp like creature in spring mountain water? I know ( traditional ) if there is leech in spring water it means it is very good to drink but it is not like leech but it is like shrimp

[image: spring Water creature like tiny shrimp]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is most likely Gammarus Pulex or "Freshwater Shrimp"

https://www.lifeinfreshwater.org.uk/Species%20Pages/Gammarus.jpg.html

I don't believe they are anything special in terms of working out whether water is potable or not.  They tend to prefer slow-moving, highly oxygenated water, but that's about it.

Comment: Commonly called "scud".

Comment: As kids, we used to call them "sideswimmers".  We also use to drink from those streams without really caring about the cows in the fields upstream.

Comment: @Snow Thanks, hope find a way to know if such water is very good true drinkable spring water. I take water from a canal come from mountain in a village in Iran, drink for  a week already. nothing bad happened but i could pop very good and lot but some feeling of thirsty. haha